# Coalessing with condition in related table

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, group-concat, mysql-5.7

I am working in MySQL 5.7.35 and I have the following tables:

```
create table Table1 (
    Id int not null auto_increment,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    primary key(Id)
);

create table Table2 (
    Id int not null auto_increment,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    Table1_Id int not null,
    primary key(Id),
    foreign key(Table1_Id) references Table1(Id)  
);


create table Table3 (
    Id int not null auto_increment,
    Type varchar(255) not null,
    Name varchar(255) not null,
    Result varchar(255) not null,
    Table2_Id int not null,
    primary key(Id),
    foreign key(Table2_Id) references Table2(Id)
);
```

Inside, I have the following data:

```
| Id  | Name       |
| --- | ---------- |
| 1   | Computer A |

---

| Id  | Name       | Table1_Id |
| --- | ---------- | --------- |
| 1   | Test Run 1 | 1         |

---

| Id  | Type      | Name      | Result  | Table2_Id |
| --- | --------- | --------- | ------- | --------- |
| 1   | Processor | MMX       | Pass    | 1         |
| 2   | Processor | SSE       | Pass    | 1         |
| 3   | Processor | SSE 2     | Pass    | 1         |
| 4   | Display   | Red       | Pass    | 1         |
| 5   | Display   | Green     | Pass    | 1         |
| 6   | Keyboard  | General   | Pass    | 1         |
| 7   | Keyboard  | Lights    | Skipped | 1         |
| 8   | Network   | Ethernet  | Pass    | 1         |
| 9   | Network   | Wireless  | Skipped | 1         |
| 10  | Network   | Bluetooth | Fail    | 1         |
```

**Desired Query**

I would like two columns `table1_name` and `test_result` where `test_result` is a concatenated string with the following logic:

For any given value in `Type`:

- If all are passes, then the result is a `Pass`
- If any are fails, then the result is a `Fail`
- If any are Skipped (poviding the first two points are checked), then the result is `Skipped`.

So for the current data, the output will be:

```
| table1_name | test_result                                                      |
| ----------- | ---------------------------------------------------------------- |
| Computer A  | Processor: Pass, Display: Pass, Keyboard: Skipped, Network: Fail |
```

**Current Query**

I am struggling to do the coalecing bit when the items I wish to coalesce are in a child table two levels down. My current query is:

```
select t1.Name as 'table1_name'
-- coalesce to happen here
from Table1 t1
inner join Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id
inner join Table3 t3 on t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id;
```

I have created a [db-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7GzGKnfwNaHvsKcaPzytyy/1) to make things easier.

Comment: Aren't other cases possible? Like Pass and Fail?

Comment: A Pass and a Fail would show `Fail`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `GROUP_CONCAT()` to collect all `Result`s for each `Name` and `Type` combination in your preferred order and then in another level of aggregation pick the the first 1:

```
SELECT table1_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Type, ': ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Results, ',', 1) SEPARATOR ', ') test_result
FROM (
  SELECT t1.Name table1_name, t3.Type,
         GROUP_CONCAT(Result ORDER BY Result = 'Fail' DESC, Result = 'Skipped' DESC) Results
  FROM Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id
  INNER JOIN Table3 t3 on t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id
  GROUP BY t1.Name, t3.Type
) t
GROUP BY table1_name;
```

If you want to preserve the order of `Type`s in the results:

```
SELECT table1_name,
       GROUP_CONCAT(Type, ': ', SUBSTRING_INDEX(Results, ',', 1) ORDER BY Id SEPARATOR ', ') test_result
FROM (
  SELECT t1.Name table1_name, MIN(t3.Id) Id, t3.Type,
         GROUP_CONCAT(Result ORDER BY Result = 'Fail' DESC, Result = 'Skipped' DESC) Results
  FROM Table1 t1
  INNER JOIN Table2 t2 on t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id
  INNER JOIN Table3 t3 on t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id
  GROUP BY t1.Name, t3.Type
) t
GROUP BY table1_name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=f550c1af899cdfe55d8f3b34f5ab86b7).

Answer (score 1):

This looks like two levels of aggregation:

```
select Name, group_concat(name, ': ', result separator ', ')
from (select t1.Name, t3.type,
             (case when min(result) = max(result) then min(result)
                   else 'Skipped'
              end) as result
      from Table1 t1 inner join
           Table2 t2
           on t1.Id = t2.Table1_Id inner join
           Table3 t3
           on t2.Id = t3.Table2_Id
      group by t1.Name, t3.type
     ) nt
group by Name;
```